# onTouchListener on FrameLayout: close it when clicked outside

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, android-framelayout, motionevent

I'm finding difficult to implement a probably simply feature.
I've a FrameLayout containing a dropdown menu (like the one in WhatsApp, popping up when you click on the Attachment icon).
I want to close it when I click outside of said FrameLayout.

I'm trying to implement it using an onTouch event, with no luck.

[image: FrameLayout]

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LinearLayout mRevealView;
private FrameLayout mRevealFrame;

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    mRevealView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rows);
    mRevealFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.reveal_frame);

    ...

}

// This method is called when I click on the right menu icon.
public void fuelTypes() {
    // Looking for X and Y coordinates.
    int cx = (mRevealView.getLeft() + mRevealView.getRight());
    int cy = (mRevealView.getTop());

    // Looking for radius when icon is tapped for showing layout.
    int startRadius = 0;
    int endRadius = Math.max(mRevealView.getWidth(), mRevealView.getHeight());

    // Performing circular reveal when icon will be tapped.
    Animator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(mRevealView, cx, cy, startRadius, endRadius);
    animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    animator.setDuration(400);

    // Reverse animation to find radius when icon is tapped again for hiding layout.
    // The starting radius will be the radius or the extent to which circular reveal animation is to be shown.
    int reverseStartRadius = Math.max(mRevealView.getWidth(), mRevealView.getHeight());

    // End - radius will be zero.
    int reverseEndRadius = 0;

    // Performing circular reveal for reverse animation.
    Animator animate = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(mRevealView, cx, cy, reverseStartRadius, reverseEndRadius);

    if (hidden) {
        // To show the layout when the icon is tapped.
        mRevealView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRevealFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        animator.start();
        hidden = false;
    } else {
        mRevealView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRevealFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // To hide layout on animation end.
        animate.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                mRevealView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mRevealFrame.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                hidden = true;
            }

        });

        animate.start();
    }

    mRevealFrame.setOnTouchListener(new FrameLayout.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Log.d("MOTION_EVENT", "getAction(): " + motionEvent.getAction());

            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.d("REVEAL_FRAME", "motion event: " + "ACTION_UP");
                    fuelTypes();
                    return true;

            }

            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

The first `Log.d()` is working, showing that the listener is triggered.
Still, the method is not going inside the `switch`: I've already tried a lot of flags, with no luck.
I've read about `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent`, but I don't know how to use them instead of the `OnTouchListener`.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: try to debug you program and see the difference between MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL and value inside motionEvent.getAction()

Comment: ACTION_CANCEL has an id = 3, while I can only see an id for the FrameLayout when clicking inside of it (usually ids are equal to 0 and 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your layout :**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"       // give id here
tools:context="com.myfuel.MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/activity_main"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/reveal_frame"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    // EVERYTHING INSIDE THIS WILL BE AS IT IS 

</FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Your Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LinearLayout mRevealView;
private FrameLayout mRevealFrame;
private FrameLayout mMainLayout;
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    mRevealView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rows);
    mRevealFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.reveal_frame);
    mMainLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    mMainLayout.setOnTouchListener(new FrameLayout.OnTouchListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Log.d("MOTION_EVENT", "getAction(): " + motionEvent.getAction());

                    //Things changed here                    

                    if(!hidden)
                       fuelTypes();


            return false;
        }
    });
    ...

}
```

As your `mRevealFrame` does not define the whole `FrameLayout` of your activity we can not use that for closing `mRevealView`. See i have defined `mMainLayout` which covers the WHOLE layout it will work now.

Try it and let me know if there is still a problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem to fix my problem, 'cause when I click outside of the FrameLayout, the Log is not showing any message. Now my menu only disappears when I click on the FrameLayout itself.

Comment: 1. we have set touch listener on `mRevealFrame` if you click out side `mRevealFrame` obviously it will not generate any log. 2. **Now my menu only disappears when I click on the FrameLayout itself** for this senetence i need to understand your whole requirement not only the `touchListner`.

Comment: I'll update the answer with an image. I'll try to re-explain my aim: closing the WhatsApp like dropdown menu when I click outside of the FrameLayout contain it (= clicking in every other place of my activity).
Thank you for your help.

Comment: update it let try to answer after that.. Please update your whole activity code too..!!

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's still not working. There's a typo in your code: an extra parenthesis befor `return false;`.
Still, even after fixing that, it doesn't work.

Comment: what is the problem?? is it going in fuelTypes() ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116557/discussion-between-davide3i-and-janki-gadhiya).

Comment: I wrote you in chat.

Answer (score -3):

Use `PopupWindow` instead of `FrameLayout`. It's not meant to be used that way.

`PopupWindow` will do what you are looking for.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html